# Implementing pause resume timer

Tags: c++

I am facing issues in creating a pause and resumable timer. I have pauseResume function to pause the execution of the code when I give certain input from keyboard and resume when I take another input from the keyboard. The timer has to run continuously until I pause it.
It is not working, can someone help me with this? How do I take input and control the loop?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using std::copy;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

// hours, minutes, seconds of timer
int hours = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;

int pauseResume()
{
    int flag;
    cout << "Program is paused !" << std::endl
         << "Press Enter to continue" << std::endl;

    // pause the program until user input
    flag = getc(stdin);

    cout << "\nContinuing .";
    sleep_for(300ms);
    cout << "...";
    cout << "\nProgram finished with success code!" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// function to display the timer
void displayClock()
{
    // system call to clear the screen
    system("clear");

    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(55) << "         TIMER         \n";
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(55) << " --------------------------\n";
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(29);
    cout << "| " << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hours << " hrs | ";
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << minutes << " min | ";
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << seconds << " sec |" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(55) << " --------------------------\n";
}

void timer()
{
    // char operation;
    // std::cout << "Enter operation: ";
    // std::cin >> operation;

    // if(operation =='p')
    // // {
    // do
    // {

    // bool startTimer = true;
    // bool pauseTimer = false;

    while (true)
    // while()
    {
        // display the timer
        displayClock();

        // sleep system call to sleep for 1 second
        sleep(1);

        // increment seconds
        seconds++;

        if (seconds == 10)
        {
            // // increment minutes
            // minutes++;

            // // if minutes reaches 60
            // if (minutes == 60)
            // {
            //     // increment hours
            //     hours++;
            //     minutes = 0;
            // }
            // seconds = 0;

            break;
        }
        // char pausePlay;
        // std::cout << "Enter p to pause";
        // std::cin >> pausePlay;

        // if(pausePlay == 'p')
        // {
        //     pauseResume();
        // }
    }
    char pausePlay;
    std::cin >> pausePlay;

    if (pausePlay == 'p')
    {
        pauseResume();
    }
    // }while(operation != 'e');
}
// }

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    // start timer from 00:00:00
    timer();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ standard input is all blocking. It stops and waits for the user to type stuff in and hit enter. Typical solutions are to put the the paused code in one thread and the user input in another, signaling between the two with an atomic flag (and in this case I'd suggest a `std::condition_variable` for the pausing and wake-up) or you use non-blocking input from a third-party console library.